# Is it possible to have language specific content?

Tags: i18n-l10n

I am working on a Drupal 7 site that is currently in English only. We are now looking at adding additional language support and so far I've got the hang of content translation using [i18n](http://drupal.org/project/i18n).

We currently have a news section composed of articles for each story. Is it possible to write language-specific articles? E.g. if there is a French-only news story, it won't appear on the English language site.

Comment: Is this drupal 6 or drupal 7?

Comment: It is Drupal 7.

Answer (score 1):

We managed to find a solution and it involved using view filters.

In case it is useful for anyone else, you can do this by selecting Edit View in the top right hand corner of the view. Click on the Add button next to Filter Criteria and then choose "Content translation: Language".

Alan

Answer (score 0):

You can have this feature in Drupal, but I recommend to start at [Multilingual Guide](http://drupal.org/documentation/multilingual) of drupal.org

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will take a look. You said that this is supported in Drupal. Can you please expand on that?